# Force mouse to hide in full screen

Tags: mouse, fullscreen

When playing some full screen players like Discovery+ in MacOS Sonoma (M2 Chip Macbook Pro), the mouse just stays on top in full screen. This is annoying as I can never really hide the mouse.

Is there a way I can get it to hide?

Answer (score 1):

To hide pointer you can try to use keyboard command <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Comment: Does that "toggle" pointer visibility? Or is there another shortcut to make it re-appear?

Comment: Thank you. When I use this, it is bringing the player out of full screen (on a stream embedded on a website), or on BBC iPlayer it is pausing the video.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/), you can assign e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to ["Show/Hide mouse cursor"](https://community.folivora.ai/t/how-to-assign-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-hide-the-cursor/18017).

That worked, as I could pick a shortcut that didn't interfere withany per-assigned shortcuts that app has (e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> which can take the player out of full screen).

Note: In some apps I need to execute the shortcut twice to get it two hide the mouse.